# problem with testing if two expressions are equal

Tags: equation-solving, expression-test

I have a small problem:

I have two expressions:

```
a = (ia*l^3*p0)/(12*ia*l + 6*i*la)
b =  p0*l^2/(12*(1 + 0.5*i/ia*la/l))
```

Obviously, they are equal. Just take expression a and multiply it by `1/(l*ia)/1/(l*ia)` and finally factor out the `12` in the denominator.

Now I would like Mathematica to tell me if those two expressions are equal, therefore I used the following code:

```
Expand[a==b]
```

But **it does not** tell me

> "True"

***Why is that?***

**EDIT:**

Writing `Reduce[a==b]` does the trick! :)
However, there is another example where it does not work:

Here is another example where it does not work

```
c = (l^3 la p0)/(24 e (2 ia l + i la))
d = p0*l^2/(24*e*(2*ia/i + i/l))
```

Again, `c` is equal to `d`. You can multiply `c` by `(1/(l*la)/(1/(l*la))` and you will get the same result as `d`.

Here I tryied: 'Reduce[c==d]`but it does not work.

Comment: I would use `Reduce` instead of `Expand`; notice you have `p0` in `a` but `po` in `b`,

Comment: @b.gatessucks thanks a lot. Now it works. Can you tell me why?

Comment: `In[175]:= PossibleZeroQ[a - b]

Out[175]= True`

Comment: `a == b // Simplify`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These expressions are not equal. c has a singularity in la, d has it not.

```
Plot[Evaluate[{c, d} /. {l -> 1, p0 -> 2, ia -> 3, e -> 4, p0 -> 5, 
     i -> 6}], {la, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> .01, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I did not notice that !